# Convert file to Base64

Tags: javascript, base64

So I am trying to convert a file from  tag. This is how my javascript code looks like:

```
var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
if (file) {
  var filereader = new FileReader();
  filereader.readAsDataURL(file);
  filereader.onload = function (evt) {
    var base64 = evt.target.result;
  }
}
```

That returns `undefined`.

Comment: your function doesn't return the `base64` value. instead of `var base64 = evt.target.result;` use `return evt.target.result;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have missed the return statement in the code.
Replace your function with the following lines:

```
var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
if (file) {
  var filereader = new FileReader();
  filereader.readAsDataURL(file);
  filereader.onload = function (evt) {
     var base64 = evt.target.result;
      return base64
  }
```

}

Comment: If this answer is useful, upvote too so that it could be used by others as well.

Answer (score 3):

two little helper and an example.

```
const blobToDataUrl = blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = reject;
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
});

const blobToBase64 = blob => blobToDataUrl(blob).then(text => text.slice(text.indexOf(",")));

for(let file of document.getElementById("file").files) {
  blobToBase64(file).then(base64 => console.log(file, base64));
}
```

### But why the Promises?

Because your next question will be: `How do I get the base64 string out of onload?` and the short answer is `You don't`. A longer answer would be: `It's like asking how to get something from the future into the now. You can't.`

Promises are placeholder/wrapper for values that will eventually be available; *but not yet*. And they are the foundation of [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

So let's skip messing with callbacks and get right to the point where you write

```
for(let file of document.getElementById("file").files) {
  const base64 = await blobToBase64(file);
  console.log(file, base64);
}
```

but for that you will have to brush up on [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).